# How to keep monolithic system up & running even when one of the components is not working?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, soa, production-environment

I am currently working on very big (monolithic) web application. We often run into a problem when one of the modules/library/component encounters some problem as one module can stall the entire application. To solve this, everyone now a days suggests to go microservices way.

But I would like to know how the similar problems were handled "before" Microservices emerged as an option? And even if we decide to go Microservices way, that will be a long journey. How can we handle this problem during the transition period?

Comment: you could try with nodemon, and set up some git versioning on the server. then when you push the fix, server will be restarted

Comment: Wow, how did you end up suggesting demon, git, fix, server restart etc

Answer (score 2):

If the monolith is truly modularized, then a failed module should not bring the whole system down. This means that every module should have its own database, for example.

Another requirement for good modularization is that a module should not make a synchronous call to another module. If one module needs data from other modules, they should do this in the background, outside a user's request.

The aggregation and orchestration of multi-module requests should be done in the Application layer. For example, if a query needs data from modules A and B, the Application sends a sub-query to A, then a sub-query to B and then combines the result and return response to client. During this request, A may not query B or vice versa. In case of partial failure, the Application may return a partial response or an error.

Also, you should have a monitoring solution for each module. This is required especially because modules have background tasks that may fail and you need to know when and how they fail.

I recommend the book [Release it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739213) for this matter.

P.S. you don't need to go microservices just for this, a good designed monolith is better.

Answer (score 1):

> We often run into a problem when one of the modules/library/component
>   encounters some problem as one module can stall the entire
>   application.

This is because all of these modules at runtime are running under the same process and share the resources. They are not isolated at runtime and can definitely affect each other by design ie, monolith.

You can minimize the impact across modules by controlling resource usage across modules, for example make sure that one module does not end up creating many threads consuming resources. Keep a watch on Threadpools and connection pools across modules. Error handling such that impacts are not across modules.